# php radio button passes wrong value to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to set multiple radio button info to mysql and it does not seem to be passing the right information on the rank radio button.  Here is my code.

```
 <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <input type="radio" name="rank" value="unranked" />Unranked
    </br><input type="radio" name="rank" value="bronze" />Bronze
    </br><input type="radio" name="rank" value="silver" />Silver
    </br><input type="radio" name="rank" value="gold" />Gold
    </td>
 </tr>

<php?
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO summoner (sumName, rank, position)VALUES( 
    '". mysql_escape_string($_POST['summoner']) ."', 
    '". mysql_escape_string(md5($_POST['rank'])) ."', 
    '". mysql_escape_string($_POST['role']) ."') ") or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

instead of getting unranked or gold I get something like this in my database: cab7e764b30007514145

What am I not doing right here?

Comment: We need to see your code that takes the values from the post e.g. your PHP code.

Comment: its all html, post your answer with php code please

Comment: also mysql_* its deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Check you PHP code:

I captured browser stream, it looks good

[image]

Answer (score -2):

this type of coding is very old, none uses it anymore, do :

```
<div>
<form actiom="my_page.php" method="post">
radio button 1
radio button 2
radio button 3
.....
</form>
</div>
```

to avoid the type of situation you are in ,and send date securely

Comment: and use css to style your form and div (position,color,width,height)

Comment: Probably for not writing understandable code (typo, badly formatted) and not describing, how your method is better to the asker. plus, it doesn't really help with the problem. Also, CSS is unrelated here.

Comment: i mentioned css because i noticed his code has a lot of style elements (border,cellpading,bgcolor ) that make the code less readable

Comment: True, but in that case, use a comment please, as "answer" suggests, that you have solved the problem. Same goes for your original post.

Comment: Ok I have found the issue.... put md5 on the tag on the import. My mistake.  Thanks for the help